# Running Jasmine tests from inbside objects

Tags: javascript, cordova, unit-testing, jasmine

I just arrived in a mid-size cordova project and would like to add unit testing to the code practices - e.g. but not necessarily Jasmine.

We are using the following "singleton function-like" pattern for simulating classes in EC5 javascript:

```
var myInstance = function( dependency1, dependency2 ){

    var _prop1,_prop2;

    function init( p1, p2 ) {
        _prop1 = p1;
        _prop2 = p2;
    }

    function foo() {
        return p1 + " foo " + p2;
    }

    function nicePublicMethod() {
        return "Public: " + foo();
    }

    return {
       init: init,
       nicePublicMethod: nicePublicMethod
    }

}
```

The dependencies are all loaded one by one in an index.html file in a following manner:

```
<script src="js/app/dependency1.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/dependency2.js"></script>
<script src="js/app/myInstance.js"></script>
```

**What I want to achieve:**

add a "public test" Jasmine function into the myInstance "singleton":

```
var myInstance = function( dependency1, dependency2 ){

        var _prop1,_prop2;

        function init( p1, p2 ) {
            _prop1 = p1;
            _prop2 = p2;
        }

        function foo() {
            return p1 + " foo " + p2;
        }

        function nicePublicMethod() {
            return "Public: " + foo();
        }
    /** TEST METHOD EXAMPLE **
        function test() {
            describe( "it tests myInstance", function() {
                it( "foo runs fine", function() {
                    expect(true).toBe(true);
                });
            } );
        }

        return {
           init: init,
           nicePublicMethod: nicePublicMethod,
           test: test // PUBLIC TEST METHOD OF THE COMPONENT
        }

    }
```

This is the only way I came up with to make sure we can unit test private methods.

Is it possible to somehow integrate Jasmine, or any other JavaScript test library/tool with these kind of test architecture?

PS: I understand this is really a general (and also way too specific) question, but the comments of knowledgeable people from this community are worth receiving a couple of -1s.

Comment: why did you test your private method?integrate test code into product code is bad thing.your test is [coarse-grained](https://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html#TestIsolation) if you want to test your private method.you must break it down to several objects to communicate with.then write all fine-grained test with each object.

Comment: as long as you find that you need test/debug a private method then your test is coarse-grained.

Comment: thanks a lot for the comment. So what you are saying is that a better approach is only public methods should be tested? Otherwise I can have a problem maintaining the tests?

Comment: test features not public methods,a feature may be communicate some methods.a story contains many features,each feature captures the process route.

Comment: you may be need some objects when you want to test your private methods.if it is true,break the private method into several objects/classes,then write tests for them one by one.